# Instagram: get photos by tag without limit

Tags: get, limit, instagram, photos

Hello im working on a instagram api, i don't know how to solve a problem. You can see my problem here down:

I want to get all photos by a tag. by now, i just can get recent photos (no more than 19 results)

```
$api = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/".$hashtag."/media/recent?client_id=".$client;
```

how can i make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Instagram API will not return all photos with a single API call, each call I think returns a maximum of 20 photos. After making the first API call, you have to use the "next_url" in "pagination" of JSON response to make another API call to get the next set of 20 images, for example you may have to implement a "show more" button which will load the next set and so on.

Below is a typical response you get from a instagram API, then making a request to API url at pagination.next_url will return you the next set of photos.

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    },
    "data": {
        ...
    },
    "pagination": {
        "next_url": "...",
        "next_max_id": "13872296"
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please help me?
how must i do to add the "show more" button?

YOU can se my code here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EFgqv